# C# Casting Generic Child Type to Parent

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let's say we have these types:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

class X<T> {}
```

Why we can't do this?

```
X<A> var = new X<B>();
```

Is there any workaround available?

**[Edit]**
I tried to use covariance but it failed because I want to access a property inside X that is of type T and C# does not allow using type T in the interface:

```
interface IX<out T> {
    T sth {set; get;}
}

class X<T>: IX<T> {
    T sth { set; get; }
}
```

**[Edit 2]**
I also tried this but it failed:

```
class X<T> where T : A
{
    public T sth { set; get; }

    public static implicit operator X<T>(X<B> v)
    {
        return new X<T>
        {
            sth = v.sth,
        };
    }
}
```

It's strange that C# does not allow to the casting for 'sth'.

Comment: In __[Edit 2]__, when you say `new X<T> { ... }`, remember that `T` can be substituted with any concrete type when this runs. What if, for example, `T` happens to be of type `class Evil : A`? Then you assign `v.sth` which has type `B` into a property of type `Evil`. But they do not have compatible types. The only "relation" between them (`B` and `Evil`) is that both derive from `A`. So a `B` is not an `Evil`, so the assignment would be illegal. Since the assignment is illegal for some substitutions for `T`, the assignment is illegal in general.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen you are right about [Edit 2]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that classes does not support Covariance and Contravariance, only interfaces:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

class X<T> : P<T> { }

interface P<out T>
{
}

...

P<A> var = new X<B>();
```

[Covariance and Contravariance FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq/)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that classes don't support Covariance and Contravariance, that's the reason we are using an interface.

Comment: I can't use covariance as I have some property of type T in A.

Answer (score 1):

You need covariance (mark the type parameter `T` with the word `out`):

```
interface IX<out T> {}
```

This is only allowed with interface types (and delegate types). And the type `B` must be a reference type (`class` like here is OK).

Then this is fine:

```
IX<B> ixb = ...;
IX<A> ok = new IX<B>();
```

Comment: I can't use covariance as I have some property of type T in A.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow you. If a property can be `set`, then `out` is not allowed because it would break things. Like if you had a `IList<Cat>`, and ___if___ `IList<>` could be covariant even if it possesses an indexer with a `set` accessor, then you could treat that list as an `IList<Animal>`, call it `animalList`. Then `animalList[0] = new Elephant();` would insert an elephant in a list of cats. Can you see now why a property of type `T` that has a `set` accessor makes it impossible to request covariance in `T`. (Compare `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which has only `get`, no `set`.)