# Casting T of interface<T> to interface<baseT>

Tags: c#, interface, casting, radix

sorry for the explanation but this is the best i can describe it, hopefully the code will help. (i've removed implementation from the classes and renamed to make it as bare bones as i can)

I get a cast exception as i convert my interface to interface   below is the code. Is there anyway i can get this to work?

```
  var instance = new Service1() as IService<PocoClass1>; //this works
  var instance2 = new Service1() as IService<PocoBase>; // this fails but i want it to work


public abstract class PocoBase
{
    public int GetAll()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class PocoClass1: PocoBase 
{
}


public interface IService<T> where T : PocoBase
{
    void Add(int x);
}

public class Service1 : IService<PocoClass1>
{
    public void Add(int x)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your base class needs to implement the Interface. Please see this SO article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705163/c-abstract-classes-need-to-implement-interfaces)

Comment: does not work either, 

var instance3 = new Service1() as IService<IPocoBase>; //(in my main method)

  public interface IPocoBase
    {
         int GetAll();
    }
    public abstract class PocoBase: IPocoBase
    {
        public int GetAll()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

Comment: the Covariance and contravariance real world example your provided, Based on that what i tried should work

Comment: this is the correct link finally found it  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615138/c-sharp-casting-generic-child-type-to-parent,  adding out to <T>